# BigQuery monitoring using Grafana via Stackdriver - no data for some metrics (like "uploaded bytes")

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, grafana, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I'm using Grafana v6.3.3 with Stackdriver v1.0.0 for monitoring BigQuery. My goal is to monitor the amount of data uploaded to BigQuery in Grafana. 
I followed the [official doc](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v6.3/features/datasources/stackdriver/) and did as it said.

I created a Service Account with role of "Monitoring viewer" as stated in the documentation.

Then, I connected it to grafana with the JSON file and it seemed like it worked - I could see the data in the graph for metrics like "Job count", "Query execution time" and "Total slots". But I don't see any data points for metrics like "Uploaded bytes", "Stored bytes" and "Uploaded rows" (even for long periods of time).

[image]

When I enter the metrics via GCP browser - I see the data.

It seems like a role problem, so I tried higher roles - I used "Viewer" role, and also "BigQuery Admin", and after that a general "Owner" - but it seemed I still couldn't see data for these metrics!

Used configuration:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated